# log4j: WARN No such property [conversationPattern] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, log4j

Tried to find an answers in other questions but nothing helped.
While running my program the log4j sent at the beginning:

```
log4j:WARN No such property [conversationPattern] in org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.
```

This is my log4j.properties file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger = warn, file


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Users\\xxxcx\\Desktop\\automationTest.log   
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversationPattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I don't understand how to solve it because i can find whats the problem with my conversationPattern property.

Any help would be great!

Comment: It should  be `ConversionPattern`, not `ConversationPattern` - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Answer (score 0):

For log4j 1 it is `ConversionPattern` and not `ConversationPattern`. That is simply change your pattern config to this:

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p
```

I think the property for log4j2 is simply called `pattern` and not `ConversationPattern`:

```
appender.file.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p
```

Comment: I think the OP is using log4j 1.2 not log4j 2 ... and it should therefore be `ConversionPattern`.